# Fn key does not work on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: kernel, updates, keyboard, bios

Recently I updated my kernel to 5.15.0-50-generic. After that my Fn key stopped working. Fn lock doesn't work either. So all special keys were lost however Home (Fn+LeftArrow) and End (Fn+RightArrow) were still working.

Then after some time I updated my NVidia drivers using apt after which Home and End stopped working too and fn mode changed to the opposite: now f1-f12 were locked while sound, brightness and other keys were working.

After that update Windows, which is installed in dual boot, lost his control over Fn key too so I suppose the problem is in the BIOS settings. However I don't have an fn toggle mode setting so I can't change fn keys behavior from there. I even tried to press functional keys in Ubuntu launched from USB drive but nothing changed there.

How can I fix it? Or at least how can I change fn mode now?

Comment: When the problem occurs in different OSes it's about neither. So why ask here? Yes, it can be a simply problem of firmware (UEFI) settings but it's unlikely, hardware failure is way more likely.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I thought it could be a hardware failure too but it's quite suspicious that it appeared immediately after the update which seems more like a bad software configuration.

Comment: According to you the problem got worse but preceded any new software. And, again, if it happens in Windows as well it's not an Ubuntu nor Windows problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: I presume it's a laptop? Try an external keyboard? At least you'll know if it's a hardware issue then.

Comment: The problem was resolved: it was a hardware problem. Not even in BIOS but in the laptop keyboard itself. Sorry and thank everyone for help.